# Multiplication with two 2D matrix to output 3D matrix

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I am wondering any good ways to calculate this type of multiplication.

It's simply multiplying `x[i]` by `x` element-wise, and resulting into `[2, 2, 3]` matrix.

```py
>>> x
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> output
array([[[ 0,  1,  4],
        [ 0,  4, 10]],

       [[ 0,  4, 10],
        [ 9, 16, 25]]])
```

I tried with code below and wondering for faster version using `numpy`.

```py
np.array([
    np.multiply(x[i], x) 
    for i in range(x.shape[0])
])
```

Comment: If I see clearly, the result is made of N vectors of squares and N(N-1) vectors of pairwise products, which all occur twice. IMO, such operations being pretty light, you spend as much time creating the resulting data structure than performing the multiplies. A better approach could be *not* to compute the big array and instead do the computation on the fly where you need it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust , Thanks for suggestion. I might consider changing logic to on the fly approach. This array should be reused a lot so I'll have to compare performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two straightforward ways to do so, the first is using [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), and the second one using [`einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html). I'd recommed using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html), to compare the various versions for their speed with the application you have in mind:

```
out_broadcast = x[:, None, :] * x
out_einsum = np.einsum('ij,kj->ikj',x,x)
```

Comment: `einsum` seems more comprehensive for me, but `broadcast` is much faster in real cases. Thank you.

Comment: Great, can you maybe add the tests you did and the results you've got? That would maybe help other people too in the future!